# Can't change input/output device (sound, microphone)

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones, input

My laptop's microphone doesn't work.
I've tried connecting wireless earpods and other headphones to it, but I cannot change the default input/output devices.

I bought a small microphone that connects to the headphone jack, but as you can see in the screenshot, it is detecting it as headphones and still using the laptop's mic, and when I click on the input or output I cannot change it to anything.

If you have any advice for me, please leave an answer :)

[image]